# How do I serve my ECS ec2 server through https?

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am working backend server launched on ECS cluster, hosted on an EC2 instance using docker.
the ECS is running great, exposed by IP address and port, but to be used with my ios app it needs to be served over https.

How do serve my ECS container over https? I have read a couple of things regarding using a load balancer, but tutorials are outdated and I can't find one that shows configuration after the ecs cluster has already been created.
Please point me to the right direction so I can get it served over https.

Comment: You need to use a load balancer. It doesn't matter if your cluster and service have already been created. You just need to add the load balancer configuration to your existing service, and possibly update your security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the following resources:

1. DNS address
2. Valid SSL Certificate
3. Load Balancer
4. Load balancer security group
5. Target Group

The target group will mediate between your server and your load balancer.
Also, in the security group define all the rules you currently have in the server security group, and in the server's security group ad a rule that open is open to all traffic in all ports with the security group instead of id.

This guide can help you:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html
(look at Create an HTTPS/SSL load balancer using the console)